# Take data from one table to another and remove any duplication

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table: **marks** & **user_student** . I want to take column data 'sid' from user_student and insert it into table 'marks' column 'stud_id'. here is my code

```
$query= "REPLACE INTO marks (stud_id)SELECT sid FROM user_student";

        mysql_query($query) or die('An Error occurred' .mysql_error());
```

The problem now is that i need each time to excute this query and i dont want it to duplicate the data but rather insert only if there is new data, else do nothing. i've try **INSERT IGNORE** also but no result. Any help please

Answer (score 2):

Insert only those `sid`s that aren't inserted already. You need another subquery to select from the same table you are inserting into to trick MySQL:

```
insert into marks (stud_id)
select sid 
from user_student
where sid not in 
(
    select * from (select distinct stud_id from marks) alias_name
)
```

Comment: It work fine, now i wish to add more values, not from the table but a custom value from colum ModuleID in table 'marks' here is my code: 

$query= "insert into marks (stud_id,moduleID)select sid from user_student where sid not in (select * from (select distinct stud_id from marks) alias_name),VALUES(1)";

Am getting error

Comment: Use: `insert into marks (stud_id,moduleID) select sid, 1 from user_student where sid not in (select * from (select distinct stud_id from marks) alias_name)`